# А нужен ли [фриланс]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Зачем нужен этот мутный [фриланс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81)?

Задачи по ней практических никаких нет, разве что какие-то юридические вопросы, которые не онтопик.

Comment: Два вопроса с меткой и оба закрыты, что тут думать-то?

Comment: @alexolut я бесхребетное существо, я не умею решать

Comment: @αλεχολυτ уже 9 вопросов.

Answer (score 10):

Т.к. все вопросы с меткой закрыты как оффтопик, можно смело убрать эту метку. Что я и сделал. Наслаждайтесь. [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0) пока не трогал.